# Change decimal places of columns instead of rows in esttab

Tags: formatting, format, output, decimal, stata

I know I can use the `b()` option in the *community-contributed* command `esttab` to control the number of decimal points displayed in the rows (i.e. the regressors):

```
estimates clear
eststo clear
sysuse auto, clear

eststo w1: regress price mpg trunk length
eststo w2: regress turn mpg trunk length
eststo w3: regress displacement mpg trunk length

esttab, b(1 3 5)
```

All of the decimal points in the first row (`mpg`) have one decimal point. The second and third rows have three and five decimal points.

However, instead of controlling the decimal points by row, I want to control the number of decimal points by column (model).

Is there a way to do this?

For example, I want all of the regressors in the first column to have one decimal point, all of the regressors in the second column to have three decimal points, and all of the regressors in the third column to have five decimal points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly but a workaround is to use a matrix.

A simple example is the following:

```
matrix A = ( -173.70800, -0.06556, -1.77658 \    ///
             -0.85469, -0.05926, 0.06587 \       ///
              21.40414, 0.16548, 3.06799 \       ///
              5853.99300, 10.76202, -342.34697 )

matrix rownames A = mpg trunk length _cons  

esttab matrix(A, fmt(1 3 5)), gaps mlabel(none) ///
collabels("price" "turn" "displacement")

---------------------------------------------------
                    price         turn displacement
---------------------------------------------------
mpg                -173.7       -0.066     -1.77658

trunk                -0.9       -0.059      0.06587

length               21.4        0.165      3.06799

_cons              5854.0       10.762   -342.34697
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Great workaround. I imagine it would be trickier to get the standard errors and stars using this approach?

Comment: You just include the SEs as rows in the matrix. The stars are trickier.